# Using modular CSS with Bootstrap 4 and React

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, postcss, css-modules

I've enabled postCSS with ModularCSS and webpack:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loader: "style-loader!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]!postcss-loader"
}
```

This means that I can now import "CSS Modules" like so:

*components/app.js*

```
import '../style/bootstrap.css';
```

This will ensure that the entire app is based on bootstrap's "global css", like resetting.

Furthermore, within components I can clearly define their dependencies on Bootstrap, e.g.:

*components/control.js*

```
import Bootstrap from '../style/bootstrap.css';

class Control extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <button className={Bootstrap.btn + ' ' + Bootstrap['btn-primary']}>choose me</button>
    );
  }
}
```

However, the syntax `className={Bootstrap.btn + ' ' + Bootstrap['btn-primary']}` is hard to read and not easy to work with.

Has this issue been tackled before? Any suggestions on how to make it more readable and workable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at React CSS modules?

Using the decorator, it seems to be very usable.

https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#decorator

You will need to set this option to true for multiple class names

https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#allowmultiple

Comment: I thought so too. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for dependencies like `Bootstrap`, though I'm not exactly sure why -- see https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules/issues/119

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [classNames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#alternate-bind-version-for-css-modules)

```
import Bootstrap from '../style/bootstrap.css';

let cx = classNames.bind(Bootstrap);


class Control extends Component {

  render() {
    let className = cx({
      btn: true,
      'btn-primary': true
    });
    return (
      <button className={className}>choose me</button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible, because CSS Modules have localized style names. I.e. it is only possible like in my edited answer, which seems even less readable than before.

Comment: it could be happening because you are excluding "node_modules" in your webpack config and Bootstrap css is there(is not it? not sure xD)

Comment: What do you mean? Bootstrap css is not there, it's loaded from `../styles/bootstrap.css`. It is being loaded. The issue is that CSS Modules (PostCSS plugin) localize the actual className, so it's not something like `btn` but rather something like `btn + some random string`.

Comment: It appears that this does work, but I had to do `import classNames from 'classnames/bind';` rather than `import classNames from 'classnames';`. Note that I also cannot do `btnPrimary: true`, but have to use`'btn-primary': true`. However, the end result doesn't seem great. Perhaps the string concatenation in my original method is more readable. It definitely results in a lot less code.